# How to bias a common-source amplifier with a current-source load in moderate inversion?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, common-source, dynamic

I am using the gmid method to design a common-source amplifier. The gmid method forgoes the use of the square-law equations for lookup-tables/charts to provide accurate results when designing circuits.

Consider the common-source amplifier shown below that is biased with an ideal current source. It turns out that to meet certain specification, the transistor needs to be biased in moderate inversion. I have found the current needed, the W and L for the transistor. However, the gmid method doesn't tell you what voltages to use. Let's say I want the output voltage to be centered at \$0.5 V_{DD}\$. How do I calculate the DC value of \$V_{in}\$. Since the transistor is operating in moderate inversion, I cannot use the square-law equations/rules. I was thinking of using an op-amp with a feedback, but this seems like a massive overkill. Any ideas how to set \$V_{in}\$?

[image]

Comment: Overkill isn't overkill if it's the only thing that does the job. My advice: ditch the FET and just use an op-amp to achieve what you want or, explain why a FET must be used.

Answer (score 3):

You simply can't set Vin in such a way that the FET is biased at half-supply, at least not reliably. The problem is that the gain of a MOSFET with a current-source drain load is so high that even the tiniest variation in input voltage (or threshold voltage!) is going to send the output straight to VDD or ground. Any tiny temperature variation is going to cause the circuit to malfunction.

Such an amplifier circuit only works when it's used inside of a feedback loop. The feedback will then ensure the correct bias automatically. An OpAmp is likely the easiest solution. You could of course design a discrete feedback circuit, too. (It'd be even easier if you just replaced the entire common-source amplifier stage with an opamp.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I had used a resistor instead of a current source, would that make it possible to set Vin without a feedback loop?

Comment: Yes, then it'd be much easier to find a proper setpoint. The gain will be lower, though, and you'll also have to use the actual quadratic MOSFET equations. You need to take channel-length modulation into account, as well as the maximum possible variation of the threshold voltage. The output bias voltage will still change quite a lot, though (threshold voltage tolerance multiplied by the amplifier's gain). It'll become infeasible if the stage's gain is greater than 10 or so. (100mV Vth variation would turn into 1V drift at the output).

Comment: Look at the datasheet of any Mosfet to see that some are very sensitive and others have low sensitivity even when they have the same part number. The curves in the datasheet are for a "typical" one then all very sensitive and not sensitive ones are different. Your circuit needs some negative feedback to reduce the variations in Mosfet sensitivity.

Comment: @Audioguru OP is designing an amplifier stage on an integrated circuit (hence the W/L parameters), not with discrete transistors. Vth can be controlled better on ICs.

Answer (score 0):

That’s not going to work without negative feedback. There’s no way to trim the input bias exactly past the threshold knee (Q point) to get your desired open-loop gain. There's too much variation in threshold to nail it exactly.

Some ideas: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/introduction-to-the-mosfet-common-source-amplifier/

This example uses *source degeneration* to provide negative feedback, but there are other techniques as well.

A differential input would allow you to bias the output to midpoint. Here's an example ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=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-BAfWua3tS27qlbg3mdwe2E1Kc4+wAPZlLYmQpJHzwdBOKGQwKliRj6i1wJ8dD2fHN+eoRdICCNSjlEAAMQg5iQbBAADVRwAbAAuAEMJkx2EA)):

[image]

The feedback resistors set the gain and allow biasing to 2.5V.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what the connection is between the differential stage and the OP's problem. The quiescent point of a differential stage is set not by the input voltage but by the bias current source in the transistor source. The transistor simply transfers (1/2 of) the bias current from the source to the drain without changing it;  for this purpose it adjusts its gate-source voltage to the required value. So, if we want to stabilize the quiescent voltage by negative feedback, it must involve the bias current source and not the transistors in the pair.

Comment: I basically reinvented the op-amp. The midpoint bias occurs because both inputs are referenced to 2.5V, and there’s negative feedback.

Answer (score 0):

## Basic idea

It is quite paradoxical because in this arrangement, two current sources are connected in series. According to the laws of electrical circuits, this is incorrect because even with a minimal difference in their currents, each of them will struggle to establish its current in the circuit. As a result of this "tug of war", the voltage at their midpoint will increase in the corresponding direction to infinity. But this "negative" phenomenon is used in modern integrated circuits to obtain something very useful - *extremely high gain*.

## Implementation

> Any ideas how to set Vin?

Here are three techniques for this purpose:

- Simply set Vin by its *parameters* window in the simulator
- Use the FET transfer characteristic
- Introduce negative feedback and calculate Vin needed from the resistor ratio

For the purposes of my intuitive explanation, I will use the first option. To show the idea in depth, I have explored below in the same step-by-step way three possible implementations - using "ideal" current sources, dynamic resistors and FETs.

### "Ideal" current sources

Strictly speaking, we cannot connect two ideal current sources in series if only because CircuitLab will not let us. To "cheat" it, we need to degrade the sources a bit by connecting very high resistances in parallel. It turns out that the internal resistance of the voltmeters (1 GΩ) can play this role.

**I1 = I2 = 1 mA:** If two 1 mA current sources are exactly the same (this is only possible here in the simulator), the voltage at their midpoint is exactly half of the supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAuoXn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**I1 = 1.000004 mA, I2 = 1 mA:** It is enough to increase I1 by only 4 nA, and the output voltage V2 increases with 2 V...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXDllQ.png)</sup>

**I1 = 1 mA, I2 = 1.000004 mA:** ... or increase I2 by only 4 nA, and the output voltage V2 decreases with 2 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsX2d2.png)</sup>

**I1 = 1.000004 mA, I2 = 0,999996 mA:** If we simultaneously and oppositely change the two currents in one...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXDpL3.png)</sup>

**I1 = 0,999996  mA, I2 = 1.000004 mA:** ... or the other direction...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUCnHG.png)</sup>

... the output voltage V2 changes with 4 V in the according direction.

### Dynamic resistors

In most cases, constant current sources are implemented as *constant-current dynamic resistors*. They are passive devices that do not contain internal power sources. Since there are no such elements in the CircuitLab library, we can simulate them with manually controlled variable resistors R1 and R2. To show that the two implementations are equivalent, I have adjusted the resistance to give the same output voltage as above.

**R1 = R2 = 5 kΩ:** The benefit of this trick is immediately visible - the initial resistance of the resistors is only 5 kΩ instead of "infinitely high".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fU2cT6.png)</sup>

**R1 = 1 kΩ, R2 = 9 kΩ:** If we decrease R1 with 4 kΩ, R2 will increase with 4 kΩ, and V2 will increase with 4 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5oLMV.png)</sup>

**R1 = 9 kΩ, R2 = 1 kΩ:** Conversely, if we increase R1 with 4 kΩ, R2 will decrease with 4 kΩ, and V2 will decrease with 4 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYriak.png)</sup>

### MOSFET

Transistors (MOSFET here) behave like the dynamic resistors above - they change its *static resistance* to keep the current constant. The only difference is that they are *voltage-controlled dynamic resistors*. So, to set the output current and accordingly, the output voltage, we have to adjust its input Vgs voltage. This is not so easy because the drain current changes drastically for very small changes in Vin around the threshold, but it is worth doing to see exactly what the transistor is doing. Now let's repeat the above experiments obtaining equivalent output voltages.

**Constant Vin1 and Vin2**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2QrdL.png)</sup>

**Vin1 increases, Vin2 is constant**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5cLkD.png)</sup>

**Vin1 is constant, Vin2 increases**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftr12z.png)</sup>

**Vin1 increases, Vin2 decreases**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiON4B.png)</sup>

**Vin1 decreases, Vin2 increases**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjGUnF.png)</sup>

### CMOS

Thus, we finally reach the idea of combining the two input voltages into one, and we get the famous complementary (CMOS) stage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKTM6T.png)</sup>